# jQuery AJAX request being treated as application/xml instead of text/xml

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, ajax

Im making a simple **AJAX** request for an XML file, but instead of text/xml
it returns it as application/xml, which apperently gives me some issues.

Code:

```
method.getXmlData = function () {
  return jQuery.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "testxml.xml?id=" + theQuizId,
    async: false,
    dataType: "xml"
  });
};
theQuizData = method.getXmlData();
```

Anyone had a similar problem?

*Note: can't include js-fiddle because of CORS.*

Comment: What issues does it give? How is this apparent?

Comment: Hav you tried explicitly setting `contentType`

Comment: `contentType : ' text/xml;`

Comment: @ClaytonMisura — It's a GET request. There is no message body to give a content-type to. (And it already has `dataType: "xml"` to tell jQuery to parse the response as XML no matter what the response content-type is).

Comment: Doen't `contentType` set the `Accept` headers on a GET request?

Comment: @Quentin The problem is that console.log(jQuery(theQuizData).html()); returns "undefined". Normally XML is returned like this when console-logging: http://snag.gy/ATuLa.jpg But in my case, it is returned in the responseText of an object: http://snag.gy/tFMdl.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by changing the code to the following:

```
method.getXmlData = function () {
var outerData;
jQuery.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "testxml.xml?id=" + theQuizId,
  async: false,
  cache: false,
  dataType: "xml",
  success : function(data) {
    outerData = data;
  }
});
return outerData;
};
theQuizData = method.getXmlData();
```

Answer (score -1):

On Which Browser you are trying the above code? 
Try using `dataType : "text/xml"` instead of xml . IE handles XML data type differntly (As ActiveXObject other browsers like chrome handle them as Simple XML). 
For Example.

```
$.ajax({ 
    url : "myUrl", 
    type : 'post', 
    dataType: ($.browser.msie) ? "text" : "xml",
    success: function(data) {
        var xml;
          if (typeof data == 'string') {
            /*This is for IE*/
            xml = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
            xml.async = false;
            xml.loadXML(data);
          } else {
            xml = data;
          }
    }
}
```

Comment: *Try using dataType : "text/xml"* — Since the questions says that the service doesn't, it seems reasonable to assume that changing that is beyond the control of the author.

Comment: *IE handles XML data type differntly* — Differently to what? Differently in what way?

Comment: Well I was saying change dataType in javascript ajax call not on server.

Comment: Oh, I misread that. Sorry. It's still wrong though. `text/xml` is not an acceptable value of `dataType`. `xml` is, but the code in the question already uses that.

Comment: updated answer with sample code to specify text or xml. Sorry for bad english